# メンテナンスのお知らせ：3月17日（土）22:00〜 JST

Tags: 討議

[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307744/planned-maintenance-scheduled-for-march-17-2018-at-1300-utc-9am-us-eastern)に示されているように、私たちは3月17日土曜日の午後10時（日本時間）にメンテナンスを予定しています。サイトは読み取り専用モードになります。 アップグレードが完了次第、正常に戻ります。

メンテナンスは1時間以内に終了することを予定しています。（詳細はStack Exchangeのページをご覧ください。）ご不便をおかけしますが、何卒ご協力のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 更新中、[ライブ配信されていた](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5tOodr4ouc)ようです :)